# Problem with .ost file when sending mail from Outlook as administrator

Tags: c#, outlook

I have a Windows Desktop application which allows the user to send mails. When the user runs Outlook and the application both as administrator and sends mail after the mail is sent user is not allowed to share any file using Send To->mail recipient. The user gets the following error:

The file `C:\Users\user name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\user name\username.ost` is in use and cannot be accessed. Close any application that is using this file, and then try again. You might need to restart your computer.

The error persists if the application is closed. Also If I re-run Outlook as administrator I am not able to send mail using sendto->mail recipient and if I run outlook normally(not as administrator) than I am able to send mail using sendto->mail.

I have checked every object related to this is destroyed in code. I found a work around to disable cached exchange mode but it is not suitable for me to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your app and Outlook are running in different security contexts, MSEMS store provider cannot share OST files between eh processes.
How are you sending messages?